# WTForms - DateTimeLocalField data is None after submit

Tags: python, forms, flask, wtforms

After form is submitted with a `POST` request, every `Field` data has its value, except `DateTimeLocalField`. Accessing DateTimeLocalField's data value is a type of `None`.

**Form**

```
class ArticleForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    category = SelectField(u'Category', choices=categories.choices)
    town = StringField('Town', validators=[DataRequired()])
    minimal_price = IntegerField('Minimal price')
    article_image = FileField('Article_image', validators=[FileRequired()])
    time_left = DateTimeLocalField('Time to end', validators=[InputRequired()],
                              format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

**Validation:** (*tested with `is_submitted`, all work except for `article_form.time_left.data` which is `None`*)

```
if article_form.validate_on_submit():

    new_article = Article(name=article_form.name.data,
                          category=article_form.category.data,
                          town=article_form.town.data,
                          minimal_price=article_form.minimal_price.data,
                          article_image=name,
                          time_left=article_form.time_left.data, # <-- None
                          description=article_form.description.data,
                          user_id=current_user.id)
```

Any help to get data from `DateTimeLocalField` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try changing the format of the `DateTimeLocalField` from

```
format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

to:

```
format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'
```

*Tip: you can print the actual content of the input field prior to the validation to confirm the correct formatting of the `DateTimeLocalField` field.*

Comment: As to why this is needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local "One thing to note is that the displayed date and time formats differ from the actual value; the displayed date and time are formatted according to the user's locale as reported by their operating system, whereas the date/time value is always formatted YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm."

Answer (score 6):

Use `wtforms.fields.html5.DateTimeLocalField` instead of  `wtforms.DateTimeLocalField`. Set the format with date and time separated by a 'T'. If you would want the current time as the default value, set default parameter.

```
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateTimeLocalField

class InterviewForm(Form):
    posted = DateTimeLocalField('Posted:', default=datetime.today, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
```

Answer (score 1):

I did extensive research on the same problem, this is a hack but I still got the timestamp from the tag which looked like:

```
<input id="time_left" name="time_left" required type="datetime-local" value="2018-11-15T04:44">
```

You basically search for the timestamp from the tag returned by the tag

```
date = re.search('(\d{4})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})[T](\d{2})[:](\d{2})',
          str(form.time_left)).group())
```

Let me know if the solution worked for you or if found a better solution to the problem.

Comment: Hi. I see you are new to stack so welcome. I got it working with answer above, I marked it as a complete. The solution you provided may work, but it's fairly complex. Python and WTForms have formating for dates and times, only it's not documented in WTForms, but in Python. That's the reason I didn't know how to format time. See more at table in link https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior